# Why do these constrained layouts have different sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

My layout is broken. I have a layout added at runtime that I anchor to all 4 sides with this code:

```
func anchorAllSides(to parentView:UIView, identifier: String? = nil ) {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let top = self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor)
    let bottom = self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor)
    let left = self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor)
    let right = self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor)
    if let identifierString = identifier {
        top.identifier = "\(identifierString) - top"
        bottom.identifier = "\(identifierString) - bottom"
        left.identifier = "\(identifierString) - left"
        right.identifier = "\(identifierString) - right"
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([top, bottom, left, right])
}
```

In the console I can see that the 2 views have constraints anchoring all 4 sides, but they also have completely different sizes.

```
Printing description of $20:
<UIView: 0x7f93084220c0; frame = (0 0; 375 205.333); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600001956ac0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000176b320>>


Printing description of $21:  
<UIView: 0x7f930840ed40; frame = (0 528.667; 375 528.667); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000017698e0>>

(lldb) po [0x7f930840ed40 constraints]
<__NSArrayI 0x600000650330>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000346a760 'drawerControllerView <-> rolePageDrawerView - bottom' UIView:0x7f93084220c0.bottom == UIView:0x7f930840ed40.bottom   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000346a7b0 'drawerControllerView <-> rolePageDrawerView - left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f93084220c0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f930840ed40 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000346a800 'drawerControllerView <-> rolePageDrawerView - right' UIView:0x7f93084220c0.trailing == UIView:0x7f930840ed40.trailing   (active)>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000346a710 'drawerControllerView <-> rolePageDrawerView - top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f93084220c0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f930840ed40 )>
)
```

The above info is printed after the view is laid out by viewing the view in the view hierarchy debugger in Xcode. So the constraints, all of which are active, should have made their sizes equal at that point.

If they are constrained to be equal, how can the frame sizes be different?

**UPDATE**

In an attempt to narrow this down, I have used breakpoint logging in the layoutSubviews() functions of both the parent VC (role page vc) and the child VC (calendar vc). In both, I log the size of the parent view for the drawer. In the child VC I log the size for the drawer view and for self.view, which is the child to drawer that is pinned on all sides to drawer. I also log the drawer view instance just to make sure they are the same. Here is the log from another run (so instance addresses have changed from the logging above):

```
role page vc drawerSize (width = 375, height = 190.5)
role page vc drawer 0x00007f7ffd516d50
calendar vc drawerSize (width = 375, height = 222.66666666666666)
calendar vc view size (width = 375, height = 222.66666666666666)
calendar vc drawer is 0x00007f7ffd516d50
role page vc drawerSize (width = 375, height = 589.33333333333337)
role page vc drawer 0x00007f7ffd516d50
role page vc drawerSize (width = 375, height = 589.33333333333337)
role page vc drawer 0x00007f7ffd516d50
calendar vc drawerSize (width = 375, height = 205.33333333333334)
calendar vc view size (width = 375, height = 205.33333333333334)
calendar vc drawer is 0x00007f7ffd516d50
```

As you can see, the drawer instance is the same. However, the calendar vc is reporting a different size for the drawer view into which it is being inserted and pinned. The calendar vc thinks its view and the drawer view are the same size, but the parent vc for the drawer view reports a larger size which is the size when displayed.

Comment: When exactly do you print the descriptions? Can you show some more code of it and how you set up the view hierarchy?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I could show more, but they are not relevant to my question. The question is why do 2 views that are pinned on all 4 sides not have the same size?

Comment: Actually it **is** relevant to see if the views are already laid out when you print to the console.

Comment: @AndréSlotta - I know. That is why I said that I printed to the console AFTER the views were laid out. That is why I don't understand how they could be different sizes without breaking the constraints. I hope that I am making myself clear. I print those sizes after the view has laid out by opening the view hierarchy debugger in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If they are constrained to be equal, how can the frame sizes be different?

Because constraints are merely instructions. Until those instructions are carried out, they are just instructions and no more. It’s like a shopping list; you can see that milk is on the list, but you do not then say “So why is there no milk in the fridge?” You also have to buy the milk.

Well, the runtime doesn’t buy the milk until later than your printing of the descriptions. Layout doesn’t happen immediately; it happens at layout time, which is after all your code has stopped running and the current CATransaction is committed. The two views will have the same sizes after that happens.

Note that I'm not just talking about the *first* time layout happens. Layout happens intermittently throughout the life of a view, as layout-triggering events happen. But *between* those moments, it is perfectly possible for other code to come along and set a view's frame manually to something else. It won't be changed back to what the constraints dictate until layout is triggered again.

(And of course that includes `layoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` themselves. Autolayout happens at that point, but your code can come along and override what autolayout did.)

Just to drive home the point, here is the complete code for an app that gets us into a situation just like what you describe:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(v)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.topAnchor),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.leadingAnchor),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.trailingAnchor),
            v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.bottomAnchor),
            ])
        delay(5) {
            v.frame = v.frame.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: 30)
            print(v.frame)
            print(self.view.frame)
            print(self.view.constraints)
        }
    }
}
```

Note the printout (I have edited out some constraints, for clarity):

```
(30.0, 30.0, 354.0, 676.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
[
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000083570 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fede9d07190]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fede9f0d230 )>, 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000957c0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fede9d07190]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fede9f0d230 )>, 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000094c30 UIView:0x7fede9d07190.trailing == UIView:0x7fede9f0d230.trailing   (active)>, 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000095f40 UIView:0x7fede9d07190.bottom == UIView:0x7fede9f0d230.bottom   (active)>, 
    ...
]
```

That's just like your printout: the constraints say the two views' edges should be equal, but their frames are different sizes. So what you're reporting is indeed eminently possible.

Comment: I have added some more info to the question to clarify that the debugger info was printed _after layout_ has occurred. That is why I have the question.

Comment: But you still have not supplied enough info for us to reproduce your findings.

Comment: Besides, the fact that you are in the view debugger does not prove that you allowed `layoutSubviews` to happen. The question is when, not where.

Comment: Not sure how to convince you that layoutSubviews has happened, but I added a debug log statement to layoutSubviews for both the parent and the child and they both log _before_ I open the view hierarchy debugger. My source code is huge, proprietary, and complex. I cannot give you all of it. My question was not could anyone reproduce the issue, it was "How can this be?".

Comment: It is up to _you_ to supply an MCVE. Right now I’d have to guess that other code, e.g. in a `layoutSubviews` or a `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, is changing the frame. Or anywhere! Changing the frame is legal.

Comment: What is MCVE? I haven't seen that acronym before.

Comment: Thanks. Before I invest in trying to duplicate such a difficult issue, I'm just trying to understand how this could happen. Here is what my current thought is: the drawer is closed (off screen) when layout happens. So the constraints are not being properly applied. When the drawer slides up by moving its frame, it does not automatically resize. I'm working on a sizing attempt right now.

Comment: We can't help since we do not know how you set up your layout, how you handle toggling the drawer, when you examine the frames and so on... The function you posted works. I used it in my example. So there must be a problem in some part of your code / setup that you are not sharing with us.

Comment: Added a couple of paragraphs pointing out that between layout-triggering events it is perfectly possible that other code can come along and change the frame. I think that constitutes a sufficient answer to the "how can this be" question. It most certainly can be. Why it's happening in _your_ app, only you can known.

Comment: Your answer put me on the right path. The calendar view needed some additional constraints to take the correct size. Thanks for taking some time to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

**@matt**'s answer exactly describes what I was trying to ask for in my comments. Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let subview = UIView()
    subview.backgroundColor = .orange

    view.addSubview(subview)
    subview.anchorAllSides(to: view)

    print("BEFORE layoutIfNeeded")
    print(view.frame)
    print(subview.frame)

    view.layoutIfNeeded() // forces the view to update its layout immediately

    print("AFTER layoutIfNeeded")
    print(view.frame)
    print(subview.frame)
}
```

This prints:

```
BEFORE layoutIfNeeded
(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
AFTER layoutIfNeeded
(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)
```

Comment: I have added more info to the question to make it clear that the sizes I printed in the console are after layout has occurred.